# F# - Result is list of list of int instead of a list of int

Tags: f#

I have quite a complex problem that I have simplified for the purpose of this question.

Let's just say the problem is as follow:
I want a list of the first 3 numbers (1,2,3) added to all of these numbers: 0,10,20

So I want the following **desired output**:

```
all = [1; 2; 3; 11; 12; 13; 21; 22; 23]
```

This is the code I have written:

```
let r = [0;10;20];;
let r2 = [1..3];;
let rshift value = r2 |> List.map (fun (x)-> x  + value)  
let all = r |> List.map (fun x-> rshift x)
```

The **actual output** is:

```
val allshift : int list list = [[1; 2; 3]; [11; 12; 13]; [21; 22; 23]]
```

As you can see, this is a `list of a list of ints`, instead of just one long `list of int`. How can I get the desired output from above?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is almost certainly a duplicate, but replace the last `List.map` with `List.collect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways. Here are some of them:

```
let adder1 l1 l2 = 
    l1 
    |> List.map(fun x -> l2 |> List.map(fun y -> y + x))
    |> List.concat

let adder2 l1 l2 = 
    l1 
    |> List.collect(fun x -> l2 |> List.map(fun y -> y + x))

let adder3 l1 l2 = 
    l1 
    |> List.fold(fun acc x -> acc @ (l2 |> List.map(fun y -> y + x))) []

let r = [0;10;20]
let r2 = [1..3]

adder1 r r2 |> printfn "%A"
adder2 r r2 |> printfn "%A"
adder3 r r2 |> printfn "%A"
```

Print:

```
[1; 2; 3; 11; 12; 13; 21; 22; 23]
[1; 2; 3; 11; 12; 13; 21; 22; 23]
[1; 2; 3; 11; 12; 13; 21; 22; 23]
```

Link:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/oUpZna

Answer (score 1):

For cases like this I kinda like the list-comprehension syntax, because it seems to be more readable for most people - so here is another possibility on top of what Foggy gave you:

```
let addAllCombinations xs ys = 
    [ for y in ys do for x in xs -> (x+y) ]
```

obvious usage:

```
> addAllCombinations [1;2;3] [0;10;20];;
val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 11; 12; 13; 21; 22; 23]
```

the obvious generalization is of course

```
let combineWith op xs ys = 
    [ for y in ys do for x in xs -> op x y ]
```

here:

```
> combineWith (+) [1..3] [0;10;20];;
val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 11; 12; 13; 21; 22; 23]
```

you should be able to use this for your *complex* problem too (or so I hope)

**fun-fact** this function is sometimes (yeah it's Haskell ...) known as `liftM2` as it *lifts* `(+)` into the list-monad ...